# Create object with list of properties and pass it to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, mvvm, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4

Perhaps there is an easy solution for my problem but I simply cannot seem to find it. I have read lots of tutorials about Knockout so I get the basics but I ask this question because my entity-structure is a bit more complicated than a person with a name and a list of friends which may or may not be on Twitter **(Video on Channel9: [Helping you build dynamic JavaScript UIs with MVVM and ASP.NET](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM08))**. Here's my situation:

I have a class ***PersonnelClass*** with this basic structure:

```
[Serializable]
//The interface is for the implementation of 'Name' and 'Description'
public class PersonnelClass : IPersonnelClassOrPerson 
{
    public PersonnelClass() : this(Guid.NewGuid(), "", "") { }

    public PersonnelClass(Guid id, String name, String description = null)
    {
        if (id == Guid.Empty) { throw new ArgumentNullException("id"); }
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        Properties = new PropertyCollection();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public PropertyCollection Properties { get; private set; }
}
```

The ***PropertyCollection*** class and associated ***AbstractProperty*** class look like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class PropertyCollection: List<AbstractProperty> { }

[Serializable]
public abstract class AbstractProperty: IEntity, IProperty
{
    public AbstractProperty(String name, String description = null) : this(Guid.NewGuid(), name, description) { }

    public AbstractProperty(Guid id, String name, String description = null)
    {
        if (id == Guid.Empty) { throw new ArgumentNullException("id"); }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) { throw new ArgumentNullException("name"); }
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public String Name { get; private set; }
    public String Description { get; private set; }
}
```

In my Controller, I create an instance of a ***PersonnelClassViewModel*** that has this structure:

```
public class PersonnelClassViewModel
{
    public PersonnelClass PersonnelClass { get; set; }
    public List<AbstractProperty> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

I fill this viewmodel with a new PersonnelClass and two test-properties to pass to my View like this:

```
var properties = new List<AbstractProperty>
{
    new TextProperty("prop1", "descr1"),
    new TextProperty("prop2", "descr2")
    //TextProperty is derived from AbstractProperty
};
var vm = new PersonnelClassViewModel { Properties = properties };
return View(vm);
```

I get everything in my View as I wanted. From the View I want to create a new PersonnelClass with a set of selected properties. I have the fields for Name and Description and to add the properties I have a ListBox with the properties that already exist (for demo-purpose they came from the controller now). Through a bit of Knockout JavaScript code I can select items from this list and populate an HTML select-control () with the selected properties to add to the PersonnelClass. This all works fine, until I want to build up an object to pass back to the Controller and create the PersonnelClass.

**My question is:** what Knockout JS code is needed to build up this object and pass it to the Controller by submitting the form and in my Controller how should I receive this object, meaning: what type of object should this be (PersonnelClass, PersonnelClassViewModel, ...) ?

If any more info/code is needed, please do ask. Thanks in advance!

**Update after answer of 'B Z':**

I followed a few more of Steven Sanderson's tutorials about this to be sure I understand this, especially the one you provided in your answer. Now I have following code in my View to start with:

```
var initialData = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));

var viewModel = {
    personnelClassViewModel : ko.mapping.fromJS(initialData),
    properties : personnelClassViewModel.Properties,
    selectedProperties : ko.observableArray([]),
    addedProperties : ko.observableArray([])
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

The variable 'initialData' contains the values I expect it to have but then I get the following error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'personnelClassViewModel' is undefined

I have no clue anymore. Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steven Sanderson has an example of how to to work with variable length lists and knockoutjs

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/

Having said that, I think your problem isn't so much on the knockout side and more on the how to databind the data correctly on the server side. In the link above, Steven uses a FromJson attribute to model bind which you may find useful...

HTH

Comment: Thanks, your given example got me a bit on the way. But please review my updated quesion.

Comment: @Abbas think if you have a new question, making a new question will help you get more responses.

Comment: You're probably right. For the initial question, your answer has been helpful so I'll mark it as the answer. The problem is almost but not completely solved but that might be another issue. Thanks anyway for your help, it is appreciated! :)